# Print something from mysql associated with another value

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to mysql and i am looking at a script right now. But im curious if this can be done or if its possible. I am new to MySQL so i might not know how this works right.

The code below prints a link associated with the category content. But I want to pull the cat_name from the right id. Is there `$row['cat_id']` into `$cat_record['cat_name']` to pull the cat_name associated with the `cat_id` from `$cat_record`. Like

Basically i would pull the cat_name associated from that cat_id.

Basically i want to print out the cat_name associated with the proper cat_id in that table. So i want to print the cat_name associated with cat_id in that table it would print cat_id 5's cat_name.

```
From Events: <a href="<?=$u?>categories/<?=$row['cat_id']?>/1"><?=stripslashes($cat_record['cat_name'])?></a>
```

Not sure if this code will help but i also have this i believe its to do with the code.

```
     if(isset($_GET['catid']) and $_GET['catid'] !=''){
     $str = "SELECT * FROM twit_info where cat_id = ". $_GET['catid'] ." order by date_submitted desc";
     $str_cat = "SELECT * FROM category where cat_id = ". $_GET['catid'] ;
     }
     else{
     $str = "SELECT * FROM twit_info where cat_id = (select max(cat_id) from twit_info order by date_submitted desc) and cat_id !=0";
      $str_cat = "SELECT * FROM category where cat_id = (select distinct max(cat_id) from twit_info)";
     }
             $twit = dbConnect($str);
            //if(mysql_num_rows($twit)>0){
              $cat_info = dbConnect($str_cat);  
              $cat_record = mysql_fetch_array($cat_info);
              //print_r($cat_record);
            // }
```

I dont know much about php or mysql but a push in the right step might help.

Comment: Because right now it just prints the last row in the table but not the one i want associated with the cat_id im looking for.

Comment: So for example it will print the right link for the category but it will print the last row cat_name in the category.

Comment: Your open to SQL Injection...

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: Please stop using `SELECT *`. Always use a column list.

Comment: Well i didnt program this but i see this is outdated?

Answer (score 0):

```
$catid = htmlentities($_GET['catid']);
```

do this instead

then do:

```
$str = "SELECT * FROM twit_info where cat_id = ".  $catid ."
```

infact i would place this into a php function and invoke it by passing the  $catid to it.